# Why do I get different base64 encodings for the same string using Powershell/.NET and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, powershell

On a webpage, I am using Javascript to convert a string to Base64:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function base64_encode (data) {
    var b64 = ""ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    enc = """",
    tmp_arr = [];
    if (!data) { return data; }
    do { 
        o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;
        h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
        h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
        h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
        h4 = bits & 0x3f;    
        tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
    } while (i < data.length);
    enc = tmp_arr.join('');
    var r = data.length % 3;
    return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}
</script>
```

That is the code from here: http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/

When I use that code the above code to base64-encode the string `cat`, it responds with `Y2F0`.

When I encode the same word in Powershell/.NET, I get this:

```
PS C:\> [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("cat"))
YwBhAHQA
```

Why are they different, and how can I make the Javascript function match the .NET output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert a string to base64, the characters must first be encoded into bytes.

Unicode encodes characters using two bytes for each character, while the JavaScript encoder you have pasted assumes that `data` is already encoded into bytes (or, at a minimum, ASCII).

Try using `UTF8.GetBytes` instead of `Unicode.GetBytes` in your Powershell script.  UTF-8 will use one byte for characters when possible, and use multiple bytes when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

base64 encodes binary data. The binary representation of 'cat' is different in JS (most likely UTF-8 encoded) and .NET (Unicode 16 bit encoded), so the base64 encoding is bound to differ.

Try to convert the string to UTF-8 (byte[]) in .NET, then encode.

Comment: Dang... you both answered at the exact same time and you're both right... who to give the green checkmark to...